# Why does eigenface have at most $N - 1$ non-zero eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, independence

I'm reading the [wikipedia article on eigenface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface). It says that if you have $N$ data points, "there will be at most N − 1 eigenvectors with non-zero eigenvalues". Why is this? Why not $N$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the matrix built from the training samples has had the mean subtracted.  That is, if $x_1,\dots,x_N$ are the columns of $T$ and $\mu = \frac{1}{N} (x_1 + \cdots + c_N)$, then the $j$th column of $T$ is $x_j - \mu$.

Verify that the sum of the columns of $T$ is $0$.  It follows that $T$ has at least one zero-eigenvalue (corresponding to $T(1,\dots,1)^T = 0$), which means that it has at most $N-1$ non-zero eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What is T(1, ..., 1) tranpose?

Comment: That's the matrix $T$ times the column-vector $(1,\dots,1)$ (which I wrote as the transpose of the row-vector $(1,\dots,1)$).

Comment: Is (1, ..., 1) the eigenvector corresponding to the zero-eigenvalue?

Comment: Am I on the right track that because we've subtracted the mean, we can re-create any one of the rows using the combination of the others, meaning that they can't all be linearly independent?

Comment: @RNdev Yes to your first question. Your second comment is effectively just stating "because we have subtracted the mean, the columns are linearly dependent", which is equivalent to my statement that "because we have subtracted the mean, the resulting matrix has zero as an eigenvalue".  Your statement is correct but I wouldn't say that you're "on the right track".

Comment: @RNdev Checking that the vector I gave you is indeed an eigenvector associated with $\lambda = 0$ would be one way to prove that the columns of $T$ are indeed linearly dependent.

Comment: Ok, I understand then why we lose the one non-zero eigenvalue. What I'm still confused about though is that these eigenvalues are of the covariance matrix of an NxM matrix, where N is the number of samples and M is the number of dimensions. Assuming N<M, why is it N-1 and not M-1? As in, why is the rank of a covariance matrix min(N, M)? I've looked for an explanation but it seems like this is just a known fact.

Comment: @RNdev The rank of $RR^T$ is always the same as the rank of $R$, and the rank of $R$ is always at most $\min(M,N)$.